# how can I add the name of the table in the pos restaurant receipt?

Tags: odoo-9

is there any possible way to add the name of the table that had the order in the printed bill of the restaurant module,and which file needs to be modified?I have already posted this question in details with all things that I have tried to add in some files but unfortunatly no one answered !!

Answer (score 0):

for all people who have interest in this I figured out how to add that field so first I thought that only the pos restaurant module files that needs to be modified so I was wrong and it's what it was all about,so the main file that should be modified is the addons\point_of_sale\static\src\xml\pos.xml ,to specifiy it's the PosTicket template,so the modification showed up right away because after all that restaurant module depends on the main point of sale

I added my code just after the shop widget like :

```
Table: <t t-esc="widget.pos.table.name"/><br />
```

and name of the table was added in the printed ticket

hope this helps you

Comment: Could you quote the exact line for the "shop widget"?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in pos ticket,

Table: `<t t-esc="order.table['name']"/><br/>`